Can a faulty power supply cause my CPU to overheat?
I am building yet another PC and have a rather old PSU in it. The motherboard is new and everything else is used but good condition.
The PSU is called „Silverstone OP750“, the motherboard is called Asus Prime B450 M-K II (in new condition).
I‘ve tested two different CPUs, both AMD Ryzen 9 3900X, and both booted.
One heated up to 65 degrees celsius in idle mode and 85 degrees in Windows 11 with nothing running, one jumped pretty immediately to 95 degrees celsius. Both had voltage in the range of 1.35 to 1.45 in idle, which is unusually high.
Could it be that the PSU is delivering way too much voltage to the CPU? Two different bad CPUs would surprise me, the only thing that stayed the same was the PSU which seems rather old and used.
Is it possible for a power supply to cause CPUs to overheat?
Edit: Now I remember I‘ve even tested a third CPU, AMD Ryzen 7 2700X, which also overheated. Very weird

Can it? Yea, lots of things are possible. You haven't give us much detail, but I don't know that it matters that much: You need to try a different PSU, if that's what you believe is the most likely cause of this issue. Also, have you checked to see whether these temps are actually problematic, bad, or outside normal ranges (eg, do you actually have a problem here, or do you only THINK you have a problem).

Since the TDP is above 100W, you should probably check that your cooling is in order. generally stock coolers are not sufficient for a chip that draws that kind of power, and of course there is lots of yin/yang between case size, air flow, room temp, etc.

“Is it possible for a power supply to cause CPUs to overheat?” - No

I would not expect the power supply to cause a CPU overheat by itself. Typical computer power supplies deliver some combination of 3.3V, 5V, and 12V power. Motherboard components downregulate those to the lower voltages your CPU and other components need (around 1.4V for your CPU apparently). If that downregulation failed, I would expect equipment damage rather than overheat.
IMHO, it is more likely that you have a cooling deficiency such as dodgy thermal paste or a heatsink+fan that isn't rated for the TDP of your CPU. According to this, you should expect to dissipate ~105W at full tilt, which is not trivial.
Also have a look at any performance features in your BIOS settings. I am not familiar with the board you mention but some settings (e.g., disable sleep states or frequency scaling) might force your CPU to run at top speed all the time. This can improve performance but has a very significant impact on heat output. Hopefully this helps.

It helped, thank you. I read somewhere else in the thread that the stock coolers are often not sufficient, maybe that‘s the problem. Thermal paste didn‘t give me problems before and seems fine. I‘ll try a different CPU cooler next
